# How to set queues manager configuration to 'optional'?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to WebSphere MQ. But when I try to connect to the logs, I see the message:

```
AMQ5540: The WebSphere MQ Client for Java application did not specify the user
ID and password

Explanation:

The queue administrator is configured to request a user ID and password,
but these data not specified.

Law:

Make sure that the application contains the correct user ID and password,
or change the queue manager configuration to OPTIONAL to allow
Connect to applications that do not specify a user ID and password.
```

How can I configure the queue manager configuration for OPTIONAL?

Comment: Are you using MQ v8.0 & above?

Comment: If so by setting "CHCKCLNT" property to optional would help.Following is the infocenter link which talks more about it.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113250_.htm. 
Here is the link for a blog written by Rob Parker which explains in more detail.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/bitesize_blogging_mq_v8_controlling_client_user_security_using_chlauth_chckclnt?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM MQ Technote "[AMQ5540, AMQ5541 and AMQ5542, application did not supply a user ID and password, 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680930)" describes how resolve this issue.

I would suggest you look at how to provide a valid username and password instead of disabling this check by setting it to `OPTIONAL`, but the above Technote shows both how to send the password from various types of applications and how to set it to `OPTIONAL`.

Comment: If you use a SSL certificate, username and password are not required I guess?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen It depends on your requirements.   You could base you security on providing a specific valid cert based on the SSLPEER and mapping the connection to a specific user by setting the MCAUSER field or using CHLAUTH rules.   You could also base it on username and password  validation.   A third option would be to require two factors,  both username and password along with a specific valid cert.

Comment: so it is either setting a SSL PEER and using a certificate, using username and password, or both. But not only a SSL certificate?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen If you don't set sslpeer anyone with a valid cert signed by a CA you trust can connect to the channel.   Setting sslpeer limits it to a specific cert from that CA.